# How to implement Taxonomy as Role?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I am building an application for a university where teachers will submit questions(MCQs) into Topics(Vocabulary) containing many terms infact in hundreds.

Our business logic is so that teachers will be allowed to submit questions only of their respective **academic field**, so we need to limit the list of topics to teachers based on their area of field. For example computer science teachers will submit questions in computer science term and its children.

So basically what I want it, something like one role per taxonomy term, I tried the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module and the user permission module, but to no avail.

Is there a better solution for limiting taxonomy terms per user? Not per role or should I then create a role against every taxonomy term?

Comment: What does MCQ mean?

Comment: Multiple Choice Questions, they are just nodes infact....

Comment: If you have hundreds of terms and therefore hundreds of roles, administering those roles could be a nightmare. A role per academic field would sound more typical.

Answer (score 0):

The [Taxonomy Term Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/term_permissions) module is what you are looking for.

From the project page description:

> This module allows taxonomy administrators the ability to restrict
>   setting individual terms on nodes by user or role.

Answer (score 0):

How about considering this question as yet another variation of either of those questions:

- [How to implement User roles for specific taxonomies?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128753/how-to-implement-user-roles-for-specific-taxonomies)
- [How to implement Node Access based on a Term in the user's profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154088/how-to-implement-node-access-based-on-a-term-in-the-users-profile)

If you agree, my answer to this question is similar to what I answered in [How to implement User roles for specific taxonomies?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128753/how-to-implement-user-roles-for-specific-taxonomies/154217#154217). I.e. that it appears to me that [organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) seems your best bet to answer your question (in this case the question is about  "**academic fields**" instead of "**cities**" or "**countries**").

Also take into account the "maintenance / development status" of any module you're considering, as explained in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128753/how-to-implement-user-roles-for-specific-taxonomies/154217#154217) in the 2nd question above, about "[Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards)". E.g. when considering [Taxonomy Term Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_permissions), as suggested in another answer here: for D7 there is no official version yet (only a beta2 release from about 2,5 year ago). Similar for [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access), suggested as a possible alternative in one of the other questions mentioned before (only a RC1 release for D7, from about 3,5 year ago).

Disclosure: I'm the author of that community documentation page (partially inspired by the 28 criteria in the issue linked near the beginning of the scorecards paragraph),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).