# How to implement User roles for specific taxonomies?

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

## Some info about what I'm working on:

- I have a taxonomy on my site called 'countries'.
- I have three 'countries' terms: "UK", "USA", "AUS"
- I have created a new user role in Drupal 7 called 'countries_admin'.

## What I am trying to achieve:

- I want to be able to add three countries_admins and assign each one a country (and be able to easily add more users when I add more terms).
- The user should only be able to create/view/edit/delete nodes which are in this term.

## My question:

Any suggestions about how to do this?

**Note**: I have tried [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) but it seems that I'd have to create a new user role for each country, which isn't really what I wanted.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a job for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)?

Comment: With [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) you can assign Roles or Users to editorial sections, and the editorial sections can be managed by Taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that there are 2 ways to answer your question. Read on for more details ...

#### Option 1: The Organic Groups module

[Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) is a possible answer to your question. It is probably the module that most users are familiar with.

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), then reviewing the amazing set of (free) videos to [Learn Organic Groups](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-organic-groups) might help.

#### Option 2: The Group module

Maybe you want to give it a try to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which is like an alternative for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

Resources:

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

#### Comparing both modules

For more details about how [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) compares to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), refer to my answer to "[What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-group-module-versus-organic-group-module/197622#197622)".